# Passing string to popup

Tags: javascript, jsp, scriptlet

I'm working with a JSP page and it's displaying a table of a storage objects that was fetched. I want to have a popup to another JSP page when the user clicks on the number that is showing the size of the storage object.

How do I pass the name of the specified storage item to the popup JSP window with Javascript (or any other technique), and then retrieve that name in the popup JSP and be able to use it in that page's code?

The scriptlet for-loop looks like this:

```
<% for(Storage s : someList){ %>
   <tr>
      <td> <%= s.getName() %> </td> <td> <%= s.getSize() %> </td>
   </tr>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass it as request parameter.

E.g.

```
<td onclick="window.open('popup.jsp?name=<%= URLEncoder.encode(s.getName(), "UTF-8") %>', 'windowname')">
```

with in `popup.jsp`:

```
<%= request.getParameter("name") %>
```

Or, more cleanly, with [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) and [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info):

```
<c:forEach items="${someList}" var="s">
  <c:url value="popup.jsp" var="popupUrl">
    <c:param name="name" value="${s.name}" />
  </c:url>
  <tr>
    <td>${s.name}</td><td onclick="window.open('${popupUrl}', 'windowname')">${s.size}</td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

with in `popup.jsp`

```
${param.name}
```